# Django: Can't migrate app installed from source

Tags: python, django, mercurial, migrate, setup.py

I have a virtualenv set up to do my install. All of these I run in a virtualenv:

```
$ hg clone https://bitbucket.org/tonioo/cmsplugin-poll
$ cd cmsplugin-poll
$ python setup.py install
```

This is the output I get: http://pastebin.com/XCX4bUiA.

```
$ cd project-dir/
$ python manage.py migrate
OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '$VIRTUAL_ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cmsplugin_poll-0.3-py2.7.egg/cmsplugin_poll/migrations'
```

As expected, cmsplugin_poll-0.3-py2.7.egg is an egg, not a directory. This works fine if I use install cmsplugin-poll via pip but I want to fix something in this package.

I already tried the following:

- Deleting and recreating the virtualenv
- Installing as root (I know--this wouldn't help anything)
- `rm -r cmsplugin_poll*` from the `site-packages` directory
- Delete and redownload the repo.
- Upgrading everything, including pip.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Instead of cloning the repo and installing it, did you try `pip install -e hg+https://bitbucket.org/tonioo/cmsplugin-poll#egg=cmsplugin_poll`?

Comment: Yes, that was able to install. Unfortunately, I want to edit the code myself. Would I be able to do this if I fork the repo, modify the code, upload the changes to my fork, and then use pip with my forked repo URL?

Comment: Okay, guess that worked. Kind of a weird work-around. Is this an issue with setuptools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your going to work on the package sources, then you shouldn't try installing it with your Python site—this will copy the sources to the interpreter's site folder, but depending on how the setup script is configured, essentials might be discarded, including test sources and other package-private bits unrelated to using it as a contributing package in other projects.

Instead you should try to do `python setup.py develop`. The sources will be only be registered  as a package path entry with your site, but you'll remain with full access to anything distributed with the package.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem occurs when installing you package with editable mode off:

`pip install ...` or `python setup.py install`

You can either install package with editable mode on (as it was already mentioned):

`pip install -e .` or `python setup.py develop`

or you can add some additional arguments to setup.py:

```
setup(
    ...,
    include_package_data=True,
    packages=find_packages(),
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

After applying these modifications you will be able to install your package properly.